# Generating nth-occurrence on rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to generate an nth-visit number for each customer's visit to a store.

Using the following query:

```
select customer_id, store_id, date from visits order by date asc;
```

I get the table as shown:

```
customer_id | store_id | date
------------------------------------------
1           | 101      | 1st November 2018
2           | 102      | 2nd November 2018
2           | 102      | 3rd November 2018
3           | 103      | 1st November 2018
2           | 102      | 4th November 2018
```

What I would like to do is sort by date ascending to append an nth_visits column such as:

```
customer_id | store_id | date              | nth_visit
-------------------------------------------------------
1           | 101      | 1st November 2018 | 1
2           | 102      | 2nd November 2018 | 1
2           | 102      | 3rd November 2018 | 2
3           | 103      | 1st November 2018 | 1
2           | 102      | 4th November 2018 | 3
```

Is there a way to achieve this in output in Postgresql? I have attempted a nested select and group by but it all went a little pear shaped.

I feel like there might be a flag I can increment but I've not been able to find such a thing like:

```
select customer_id, store_id, date, occurance(customer_id, store_id) as nth_visit from visits order by date asc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for that:

```
select customer_id, 
       store_id, 
       "date", 
       row_Number() over (partition by customer_id, store_id order by "date") as nth_visit 
from visits 
order by "date" asc;
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked - just reading over the docs I can see various situations where window functions would have been suitable so I'm going to study that in more detail.